# INTERNAL SERVER ERROR LARAVEL Y COMO BUSCAR DATOS ESPECIFICOS

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hola soy nuevo en Laravel y tengo un sistema de casos y ticke hecho en Laravel, el problema es que actualmente he presentado muchos incovenientes con el sistema ya que me aparecen muchos errores cuando intento añadir nuevas tablas me aparecen errores inexperados como por ejemplo estos dos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde en la ultima no se de donde coloca esa S a la tabla categoriainv y se arregla si modifico el nombre de la tabla desde mysql, por lo que mi pregunta esta mas enfocada en saber si alguien sabe como buscar en VisualStudio Code donde se ejecuta esta palabra o donde lo podria modificar, ya que busco internamente la palabra y los datos a modificar pero no aparecen.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el modelo de tu tabla, incluye la siguiente linea, eso te permite sobreescribir el nombre de la tabla, en tu proyecto, asi evitas la normalizacion automatica que se hace

```
protected $table = 'nombre_tabla';
```

Comment: muchas gracias no sabia que se podian seleccionar las tablas que uno elegia, pense que todo era utomaticamente normalizado pero si me funciono. solo que para que hiciera efecto tuve que limpiar cache para que lo tomara al final

Answer (score 1):

Ya te respondieron con una manera de evitar la excepción que muestras, pero me parece importante que entiendas por qué sucede y puedas tomar una decisión informada, además de que también le pueda servir a otros lectores.

Aunque no muestras el código de la consulta a la BD, por el error se asume que estás usando Eloquent.
Si buscamos en la documentación de Laravel, la explicación está en: [Eloquent: Table names](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#table-names)

> By convention, the "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified. So, in this case, Eloquent will assume the `Flight` model stores records in the `flights` table, while an `AirTrafficController` model would store records in an `air_traffic_controllers` table.

Que traducido vendría a ser algo así:

> Por convención, se utilizará como nombre de la tabla el nombre de la clase (el modelo) en plural y en "snake case", a menos que se especifique explícitamente otro nombre. Entonces, Eloquent asumirá que para el modelo `Flight` se almacenarán los registros en la tabla de `flights`, mientras que para un modelo `AirTrafficController` se almacenarían los registros en una tabla `air_traffic_controllers`.

En fin, veo dos posibilidades:

1. Seguir las convenciones de laravel y nombrar los modelos en *singular* (típicamente un sustantivo en singular, a veces con algun modificador como en el segundo ejemplo) y a las tablas con el mismo nombre en *plural*.
2. Puedes definir el nombre de la tabla en la propiedad `$table` del modelo como te dicen en la otra respuesta.

Comment: muchas gracias la documentacion es muy clara y tambien hay varias ideas que voy a tomar de ese documento, para mi proyecto y seguir testeando con lavarel, que es nuevo para mi pero muy interesante